# Future's .recover not getting called when Exception is thrown in Mockito unit test

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

The following code returns a Future.

```
val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.findOne(userKeys)
```

Then I process the Future

```
findUserFuture.flatMap {....}
.recover{...}
```

`fineOne` returns the `Future` and the `Future` wraps call to `getOneById`

```
def findOne(userKeys:UserKeys):Future[Option[User]] = {
    Future{
      //val loginInfo:LoginInfo = LoginInfo(userKeys.providerID,userKeys.authProvider)
      val userOption:Option[User] = getOneById(userKeys)
      userOption
    }
  }
```

I suppose that recover will be called if `Future` returned by `findOne` fails i.e. throws an Exception. So I am simulating that by making `getOneById` throw an exception.

```
when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
      when(mockUserRepository.getOneById(userKeys)).thenThrow(classOf[RuntimeException]) //simulating database error
```

But the unit test doesn't throw an exception and the test proceeds using value `Future(Some(User))`.

I also tried throwing the exception from `findOne` - `when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenThrow(classOf[RuntimeException])` but the test case stops 
with the following two prints and the `.recover` of the `Future` is not called

```
java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown.
java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]]` or `userRepo.findOne` returns future,
hence you need to return `Future.failed` in your mock.
For ex.

```
when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
when(mockUserRepository.getOneById(userKeys)).thenReturn(Future.failed(new RuntimeException("network failure"))
```

Find below complete working test to simulate your use case :

```
test("mock future test") {
    case class User(name: String)
    case class UserNotFoundException(name: String) extends Exception
    trait UserRepo {
      def findOne(name: String): Future[Option[User]]
    }
    val name      = "bob"
    val dummyUser = User("dummy")

    val userRepo = mock[UserRepo]
    when(userRepo.findOne(name)).thenReturn(Future.failed(new RuntimeException()))

    val userF = userRepo
      .findOne(name)
      .flatMap {
        case Some(user) ⇒ Future.successful(user)
        case None       ⇒ Future.failed(UserNotFoundException(name))
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(_) ⇒ dummyUser
      }

    userF.futureValue shouldBe dummyUser
  }
```

- Update *
  After looking at the original post closely, I found small mistake in the way you are mocking.
  try below:

```
when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenCallRealMethod()
when(mockUserRepository.getOneById(userKeys)).thenThrow(classOf[RuntimeException])
```

Notice `thenCallRealMethod()` here, earlier you were mocking `findOne` to return future with successful value which means original method was not getting called which in turn was not calling `getOneById`

Comment: getOnById returns Option, he's trying to test and mock the same type, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: that also works with below:
```   
when(userRepo.findOne(name)).thenCallRealMethod()
when(userRepo.getOneById(name)).thenThrow[RuntimeException]
```

Comment: True that, although mocking the type under test is wrong in many many ways

Comment: @Bruno - It will help me learn if you could please explain what is wrong in my design. What do you mean by `mocking type under test`?

Comment: The point of your test is to ensure the correct behaviour of a class or trait (a type), for it, you provide some inputs to an instance of that type and ensure that what comes out, sometimes, your type depends on other componets, but you don't wanna deal with them as your are only interested in testing that unit of code (your type), so that's why mocks come handy, you replace those dependencies by mocks as you just want them to behave in certain way, now, if you mock the type you want to test, you're effectively removing the behavior that you wanted to test in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock the type you want to test, a mock has nothing of the original behaviour of that type.

If you wanna stub just some behaviour of the class under test (or any other type), you should use a spy, then you would only do

```
when(spyUserRepository.getOneById(userKeys)).thenThrow(classOf[RuntimeException])
```

then call `spyUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)` and assert that it returns a Failed future

That said, it seems you have the responsabilities a bit mixed up here, I'd suggest having a second look to your design as having to resort to use spys for this looks like a big code smell for me.